how to deploy QT application on windows in a customised way?
as far as I know, after the project compiled successfully, I will get a some.exe. If I want to deploy it , I need to copy some files, such as Qt5Core.dll at least to the same directory. And now the some.exe will run normally.
however, I want to pack the Qt dependencies in a seperate directory. at the beginning of the some.exe, it should add Qt dependency's path to system path variable, then the application will run as usual. I tried, but failed. I coded it with Windows GetEnvironmentVariableW and SetEnvironmentVariableW APIs, the Qt's bin path is added to the system path with certainty.
but the app still runs with Qt5Core.dll missing error. I've tried add the bin path to system path variable manually, the app then run normally. I cannot figure out why it's different programatically.

If you link statically to the DLL, the OS resolves its path before any code is executed, hence the error. If you want to manipulate the search path in code, you have to load the DLL dynamically at runtime instead, then you can use SetDllDirectory() or AddDllDirectory() (don't manipulate the PATH environment variable) before loading the DLL. I dont know if Qt supports being loaded, dynamically, but you might try using your compiler's delay-load feature, if it has one. Otherwise, you will have to create an installer that setups the environment the way you want.

@RemyLebeau I've tried the SetDllDirectory() or AddDllDirectory(), it still doesn't work.
and I've tried another way to add the environment variable path, that is, by operating registry, which will set the path permanently. I remember I almost doing the same thing with Python/C api in the past days, the compiled some.exe should stay in the same directory as python3.dll or the DLL should be added into enviroment path variable, otherwise there is python3.dll missing error. After all, thanks

Maybe, you could take a look at windeployqt utility https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html
Your deployment seems to be like this:
windeployqt some.exe --release


thank you. I know how to config with windeployqt
